# What are some good ideas to practice /s/ sound in conversation?

Tags: pronunciation

I have been learning English for seven months. I know the basic grammar rules of final /s/, for example, she like**s** ..., he love**s** ..., and so on.

In Thai language, we don't have /s/, /k/, /t/, and other sounds that flow the air out of the mouth.

My problem is during conversation. I usually forget to pronounce final /s/ and sometimes /s/ at the middle of the word. Even I read aloud to my teachers, I still drop those sound. I want to break this habit. I would like to know some good ideas to practice and retain final /s/ and /s/ at the middle of the word.

Comment: This sound is really important in English, and you’re right to be concerned about it.

Comment: A random search led me to http://www.youtube.com/user/pronunciationmeg/videos?query=sibilants which might be of some assistance. Using the word _sibilant_ in your search queries should lead you to additional resources.

Comment: This may be off topic.  Per [faq]: «But please, don’t ask any questions about the following topics. … "How to improve my English?"»  It might be on topic in proposed [english-language-learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners); become a follower there if interested.

Answer (score 2):

The best idea I can think of is to read out a passage from some book out loud, and then consciously correct yourself. Doing this everyday for an hour or so would improve your condition.
Even I faced a similar problem, I sort of stammered, so my English professor told me this way to improve it.